# Do Fate's licenses allow including core rulebook text in a for-profit expansion?

Tags: fate, publishing

Is it supported by either or both of Fate's licenses to include passages of significant length from the Fate Core and Fate System Toolkit rulebooks in a Powered By Fate game of your own design that you intend to sell for profit?

Specific case relates to the use of skills: if you would like to publish a heavily modified skill list, which contains skills that are unchanged from their Core incarnation, would it be within the rights granted by the licenses to reuse their descriptions from the original Evil Hat books?

My understanding is that OGL is viral (please correct me if I'm wrong) and therefore I would have to use CC-BY license to publish for profit. Please refer to that license when answering.

Comment: Similar question here: [Can I use existing game mechanics in my own designs?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21324)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I run Evil Hat and am one of the originators of Fate, so I've got some XP to spend on this one. :)

In either case you can include the entire content of the SRDs available on the Fate licensing site (see link below).

OGL isn't viral per se, it simply stipulates you cannot close off content which was made open to you (the stuff you're reusing). I have done OGL-derivatives where my product identity declaration is in effect "this entire product, excluding portions inherited, is product identity". Folks might get a little upset about that if they're big open content advocates, but it's entirely allowable.

CC-BY, yes, you just need to provide the indicated credit declaration and you're good to go.

Folks make for-profit products based on content from both versions, have done so for well over a decade in fact. :)

Further details about Fate's licensing schemes are available in great detail at this page and in the pages linked from it: http://www.faterpg.com/licensing/

Comment: Can't top that answer!